# Google Chrome and Safari, my website gives extra space on the right side

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I have this site...

http://willruppelglass.com/

and it looks good in IE9, 8, 7, Firefox but in Google Chrome and Safari (if you scroll over to the right side) you will a blank space, why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advanced,
J

So apparently this issue is in all browers..here is my body css code...

```
body{
    font-family: 'ArialNarrow';
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I added a screen shot on what my issue now is..

[image]

Comment: I don't know how you are testing, but the issue is apparent in all browsers: Firefox 12, Chrome 18 and IE9, IE8 and IE7.

Comment: ummm... do you know how to fix it?

Comment: i don't see how it's possible to scroll over to the right; no scroll bars

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your `body` but it lies with your `.headerNav`

```
.headerNav {
    color: 
    black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-left: 230px;
    }
```

You give it a width of 1280px but then you give it a padding-left of 230px which makes the actual width = 1510px which is adding the horizontal scrollbar to the site.

I would recommend the following

```
.headerNav {
    color: 
    black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1050px; /* decrease the width of the div to compensate for the padding-left */
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-left: 230px;
    }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Quickest to the draw. You still have 50k + more than me ;)

Comment: this works and http://willruppelglass.com/ looks fine on my end, how about yours?

Comment: now someone is saying that the black header at the top doesnt go all away across. any ideas?

Comment: I can't see that problem, ask them to tell you which browser they are on and the screen resolution etc and we can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10983/discussion-between-user1193385-and-trickeedickee)

Comment: he is using Safari 5.1.5 and doesnt know his screen resolutions